# Firewall rules default range value for all new rules on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm one question about networking on Google Compute Engine.

Is there any possibility to set default "Source tag / IP range" on your account to get this value automatically set when new rules is created?

For example, if I create this rule:

```
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create "test-net1-ssh-in" \
  --allow tcp:22 \
  --network "test-net1" \
  --source-ranges "0.0.0.0/0" \
  --target-tags "ssh-servers"
```

Will replaced (automatically of course) by:

```
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create "test-net1-ssh-in" \
  --allow tcp:22 \
  --network "test-net1" \
  --source-ranges "8.8.8.8/32" \
  --target-tags "ssh-servers"
```

And why this should be useful? Because we want that every rule created on the platform, custom rules or auto-generated rules (from kubernetes cluster) will allow only or testing computer IP

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an option in Google Compute Engine at the moment, but the feature that you're looking for will at least [be worked on in Kubernetes soon](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20392).

Comment: Hi Alex, then it's enough, because we manage our deployments with scripts that add automatically that rules and only kubernetes is non-covered.

Comment: It might be interesting to evolve policy for per-namespace rules like "all services in this NS must have source IPs set to X"